# Custom Auto Imports in Nuxt 3 (Auto Import Pinia Store)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pinia, nuxt3

Is there a way to set custom auto imports in Nuxt 3? I use Pinia and my stores are in the root directory under /stores.
For example, if I want to use the store from /stores/auth.store.ts in a component, I always have to import the store like this:
`import { useCourseStore } from '~~/stores/course.store';`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As defined on Pinia doc https://pinia.vuejs.org/ssr/nuxt.html#auto-imports, you can set this config in your `nuxt.config.ts`

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // your config...
  modules: [
    [
      '@pinia/nuxt',
      { autoImports: ['defineStore'] },
    ],
  ],
});
```

And you can also define custom import dirs in your config https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#imports

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // your config
  imports: {
    dirs: ['stores'],
  },
});
```

Comment: The Docs say "It also automatically imports all stores defined withing your stores folder." but my Store is not found out of the box 

Answer (score 1):

[Tristan's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75825950/6688256) pointed in the right direction, in the meantime the nuxt.config.ts syntax has changed a little:

```
// nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // ... other options
  modules: ['@pinia/nuxt'],
  pinia: {
    storesDirs: ['./stores/**', './custom-folder/stores/**'],
  },
})
```

Source: https://pinia.vuejs.org/ssr/nuxt.html#auto-imports